# How to compute the maximum of Column B after having filtered by the contents of Column A?

Tags: google-sheets

I have data in two columns (say A2:B20). To get what I want, I have to filter by the first column, and then get the maximum value in the second column of the filtered array. Can this be done without a custom function? If not, what would the custom function be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula

```
 =MAX(FILTER(A:A, B:B="something"))
```

gives the maximum of the entries in the A column for which the corresponding entry in B column is "something". See [documentation for `FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en).